# R: apply function to matrix columns, but only to certain values (referring to another matrix)

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply

Say I have two matrices, `data_matrix` with my data, and another `boolean_matrix` with the same structure, but just 1s and 0s, specifying those values from `data_matrix` I want to grab.

They look like this:

```
> set.seed(42)
> data_matrix=matrix(runif(100,0,5), nrow=10)
> boolean_matrix=matrix(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), nrow=10)
> colnames(data_matrix)=LETTERS[1:10]
> colnames(boolean_matrix)=LETTERS[1:10]
> head(data_matrix)
            A        B         C          D         E         F         G
[1,] 4.574030 2.288709 4.5201569 3.68797809 1.8977962 1.6671361 3.3780364
[2,] 4.685377 3.595561 0.6935508 4.05527571 2.1788579 1.7337412 4.9140860
[3,] 1.430698 4.673361 4.9444586 1.94054141 0.1871552 1.9924271 3.7977213
[4,] 4.152238 1.277144 4.7333412 3.42584865 4.8676996 3.9234639 2.8324421
[5,] 3.208728 2.311464 0.4121878 0.01974169 2.1587562 0.1946825 4.2484486
[6,] 2.595480 4.700073 2.5710589 4.16458040 4.7878830 3.7439769 0.9473697
             H        I           J
[1,] 0.2149440 2.908020 3.337132573
[2,] 0.7023955 0.789526 0.001194483
[3,] 1.0819271 1.795142 1.042849785
[4,] 2.3969928 3.228159 4.665170637
[5,] 0.9870517 3.879117 4.628223743
[6,] 3.5967792 2.818234 3.670471505
> head(boolean_matrix)
     A B C D E F G H I J
[1,] 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
[2,] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
[3,] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
[4,] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
[5,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
[6,] 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0
```

What I want to do here is very simple, I just want to run simple functions to `data_matrix` columns, like `max`, `min`, `length`, etc.

```
> apply(data_matrix, 2, max)
       A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H
4.685377 4.891132 4.944459 4.533007 4.867700 3.923464 4.914086 3.596779
       I        J
3.879117 4.665171
> apply(data_matrix, 2, min)
          A           B           C           D           E           F
0.673332986 0.587436808 0.412187790 0.019741694 0.187155164 0.194682456
          G           H           I           J
0.947369677 0.007852771 0.428060325 0.001194483
> apply(data_matrix, 2, length)
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

HOWEVER, I want to do it only for those values in `data_matrix` that have a 1 in `boolean_matrix`... Not sure how to pass this to the `apply` function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `as.logical()` we can turn the your `boolean_matrix` in to a `logical` (`TRUE`/`FALSE`)
matrix.

```r
logical_matrix <- as.logical(boolean_matrix)
logical_matrix
#>   [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [13]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [25]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#>  [37]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#>  [49] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#>  [61]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [73] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [85]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#>  [97]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`logical_matrix` can now be used to index `data_matrix`. We do that and set
all cells to `NA`, that are not `TRUE` in `logical_matrix` , and hence have a `0` in `boolean_matrix`.

```r
data_matrix[!logical_matrix] <- NA
```

By specifying `na.rm = TRUE` we can now use apply in combination with functions as
`min()`, `max()` etc. to obtain the results only for the selected cells.

```r
apply(data_matrix, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE)
#>        A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H 
#> 4.574030 4.700073 4.944459 4.533007 4.867700 3.743977 4.914086 2.572039 
#>        I        J 
#> 3.879117 3.719873
apply(data_matrix, 2, min, na.rm = TRUE)
#>           A           B           C           D           E           F 
#> 0.673332986 2.288708881 0.412187790 0.019741694 2.158756244 0.194682456 
#>           G           H           I           J 
#> 3.378036373 0.007852771 0.449902582 0.001194483
apply(data_matrix, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#>         A         B         C         D         E         F         G         H 
#> 3.0032456 3.2494025 3.4582861 2.7691708 3.7535582 2.0340574 4.0845731 0.9423418 
#>         I         J 
#> 2.0022194 2.1205560
apply(data_matrix, 2, median, na.rm = TRUE)
#>        A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H 
#> 3.246845 2.801664 4.354356 3.425849 3.993888 1.992427 4.023085 0.214944 
#>        I        J 
#> 1.993376 2.380578
```

You also mention that you want to use `length()` in the same fashion. `length()`,
returns the same value for each column though, since it also counts the cells
with `NA`.

```r
apply(data_matrix, 2, length)
#>  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J 
#> 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Maybe `apply()`ing `sum()` to `boolean_matrix` returns the result you are looking for here.

```r
apply(boolean_matrix, 2, sum)
#> A B C D E F G H I J 
#> 6 7 6 9 4 5 4 5 6 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only positive numbers in `data_matrix` you can multiply it with `boolean_matrix` so that values that are 0 in `boolean_matrix` would also become 0 in `data_matrix`

```
new_matrix <- data_matrix * boolean_matrix
```

You can then apply all the functions on `new_matrix`.